# cross origin error in web api 2 c# - Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain, asp.net-web-api2

I have tried all ways to work out this  cross origin problem. But i couldn't figure out whats the issue.

I added This is my webapiconfig.cs

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
 config.EnableCors(cors);
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

and in webconfig

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);   
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Response.Flush();
        }
    }
```

and I added nugget package `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`

Kindly help me guys!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the following code in **web.config** file of your Web API:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a controller named `TestController` then you have to enable cors in your `Get method` like below

```
public class TestController : ApiController
    {
            [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
            public string Get()
            {
                return "Hello world";
            }

   }
```

others methods also like this.

Useful link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: then the problem is somewhere else, its working solution I have used